# Is it possible to overwrite community url namespace?

Tags: community

In every community, each community page is with URL under `/<COMMUNITY_NAMESPACE>/s/`
How could I overwrite the `/s/` to anything else? or even get rid of that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a community builder thats why this `\s` has appended in community url.

I don't think you can remove it as this is a standard feature.

But you can [Run your community under a custom domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212707&type=1) that will allow you to change the domain completely. You can follow the steps.